# How to setup Kubernetes to support dynamically added subdomains?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have own service with subdomain for each client (client1.mydomain.com). Which tool is better to use to have ability to add new service/subdomain. One of the solutions is ingress Nginx, but to update "rules" for adding a new client (client2.mydomain.com) this cause downtime for the rest of clients.

Answer (score 2):

Traefik can hot-reload those rules which could be provided by multiple configuration backends.

We only need to enable watch option to make Traefik watch configuration backend changes and generate its configuration automatically. Routes to services will be created and updated instantly at any changes.

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/basics/#dynamic-traefik-configuration

Comment: I would consider isolating clients from one another. (namespace per client ) So you can assign quotas and quality of service for each client not allawing that the load of one client affects the performance of other clients... and also solving other complications and possible downtimes.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx ingress controller doesn't require downtime for updates, it just degrades performance during updates. It can achieve this by hot reloading. Your use case is very common one to use ingress.